# byte[] to String conversion with proper truncation in Java

Tags: java, string, truncate

I have a byte array of size 200 that has data received with `socket.receive()`. Let's say the packet data is "hello".

```
int size = 200;
DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(new byte[size], size);
socket.receive(packet);
byte[] byte1 = packet.getData();
```

I tried to convert the byte array into string, and the string length is 200 even though it prints out only 'hello' string.

```
String result = new String(byte1); // .toString();
System.out.println(result.length()); --> 200
System.out.println(result); ---> hello
```

How can I truncate the String to contain only "hello" when converting it from byte[]?

### ADDED

Based on malchow's answer, this solved my issue:

```
int packetLength = packet.getLength();
byte[] byte1 = packet.getData();
String result = new String(byte1);
return result.substring(0, packetLength);
```

Comment: If the extra bites are all empty/whitespace, trim() should do it.

Comment: Something's fishy here. How do you, as a client, know when you've received the entire string? That is - what way do you have of knowing that you've gotten all of the character data?

Comment: This is a part of unit test code, so I know exactly the string I sent.

Comment: @Thomas: It works. Please make an answer so that I accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe you should try to check the length of the data received AFTER receiving it:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/net/DatagramPacket.html#getLength%28%29

this should be 4 (after the call to socket.receive())

Comment: the "setLength()" method is for sending, not for receiving.

Answer (score 0):

If the extra bites are all empty/whitespace, trim() should do it.

Comment: this is actually incorrect if the message in the datagram is SUPPOSED to contain leading and/or trailing whitespace. please consider my answer below (with a link to the documentation)